# A circle permutation problem.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, permutation-cycles

Four white beads, two red beads, and two blue beads are strung together to form a necklace. How many ways are there to string the beads?

By the way, the beads are indistinguishable.

Respond to @Arthur: Assume flip a necklace over and still have the "same" necklace? Eg. two red beads, and two blue beads can be strung into two kinds of necklace.

Thanks for @Robert Shore. My thought is to order all heads first, then cancel the order of beads of the same color. like $\frac{A_8^8}{A_4^4A_2^2A_2^2*}$. But clearly, there is a symmetric issue that should be considered like @Arthur pointed out.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  What tools are available to you to solve the problem?  Please **edit the question** to provide this information.  Questions that show no evidence of any independent effort to reach a solution usually are not well received here.

Comment: I'll ask the second question again, with an example: Can you move a bead from one end to the other? How many distinct necklaces can two blue and one red bead make? Also, does "Burnside's lemma" sound familiar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Necklace problem with Burnside Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827211/necklace-problem-with-burnside-lemma)

Comment: As to say how many eight-digit numbers can be formed with four digits 1, two digits 3 and two digits 5?

Comment: @Piquito  That is a different question since the objects are arranged in a line.  In this question, two arrangements are considered to be equivalent if they can be obtained from each other by rotation and/or reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $4$ white and $2$ red beads. There are $3$ bracelets (necklaces where flips are equivalent).

```
W W W W R R
W W W R W R
W W R W W R
```

Now position the $2$ blue beads, looking at each case separately.

There are at most $28$ positions for the $2$ beads over each necklace, but this estimate is far too large.

```
B B W W W W R R
B W B W W W R R
B W W B W W R R
B W W W B W R R
B W W W W B R R
W B B W W W R R
W B W B W W R R
W B W W B W R R
W W B B W W R R

B W W W W R B R
W B W W W R B R
W W B W W R B R

W W W W R B B R
```

13, and

```
B B W W W R W R
B W B W W R W R
B W W B W R W R
B W W W B R W R
W B B W W R W R
W B W B W R W R

B W W W R B W R
W B W W R B W R
W W B W R B W R
W W W B R B W R

W W W R B B W R
W W W R B W B R
```

12, and

```
B B W W R W W R
B W B W R W W R
B W W B R W W R
W B B W R W W R

W B W R W B W R
W W B R W B W R
W W B R B W W R
W W B R W W B R
```

8, for a total of 33.

Comment: this is missing several: there are *33* total. 7 are missing: `bwwwrbwr wbwwrbwr wwbwrbwr wwwbwrbwr wwwbrbwr bwwrwbwr bwwrbwwr bwwrwwbr`); you also have `bwwbwrwr` and its mirror `wbwwbrwr` both counted.

Comment: @DanUznanski; thanks, I've fixed it.