# Circular arrangement of equal quantities of letters or objects

Tags: combinatorics

How  many ways are there to arrange the letters $A$, $A$, $B$, $B$ around a circle?

My first go with was is to arrange $4$ objects around a circle with gets us $(4-1)!$ but we have to take care of the inner arrangements of $A$, $A$ and $B$, $B$ which leaves us with $$\frac 6 {2! \cdot 2!}  $$  but that's obviously wrong. I have tried other methods too but they fail to generalize.

By counting by hand for both the $2A$'s and $B$'s case and the $3A$'s and $3B$'s case we get the answers $2$ and $4$ respectively (hopefully I didn't make any mistakes counting)
[image: the arrangments i got]

- what's wrong with my argument?
- what's the right method for solving this?
- how can this be generalized?

Comment: Have you heard of burnside's lemma?

Comment: no, I haven't heard of it and I'm looking at how it applies right now, but I also want to know why is my argument wrong?

Comment: Why is your argument wrong?  The guess of $\dfrac{(2k-1)!}{k!k!}$ for the number of circular arrangements of $2k$ objects half of which of one type and half of the other?  Well, for starters, it should be clear that the guess isn't even an integer for several $k$, in particular for $k$ prime.  Now... you could I suppose use this to count the arrangements of $k$ A's, $k-1$ B's and $1$ C as $\dfrac{(2k-1)!}{k!(k-1)!}$, and the logic of which is that you can use that $C$ as a reference point.  You can't really do that when the intended reference point can be confused with other points however.

Comment: Please see - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810598/possible-combinations-of-4-pieces-of-a-and-4-pieces-of-b/3811108#3811108

Comment: One of my own questions I posted that is related: [When is $\binom{2n}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2n}$ an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700613/when-is-binom2nn-cdot-frac12n-an-integer) and the question that inspired me to ask it: [arrangement of $n$ oranges and $n$ apples around a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698695/arrangement-of-n-oranges-and-n-apples-around-a-circle/) where another answerer (now deleted) makes the same mistake as you.